# Couldn't find Post with 'id'=testuser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I go to delete a post I get the error "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=testuser". I think this is a routing error as I believe the id being ran should be that of the Post and not the User? I can't work it out. I can create posts but can't delete or edit for the same reasons.

I can provide more information if needed.

The extracted source in PostController#destroy is where:

```
def set_post
@work = Work.find(params[:id])
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
resources :posts do
end

# Define route URL
root 'pages#index'

# Define routes for Pages
get '/home' => 'pages#home'

get '/user/:id' => 'pages#profile'

get '/new' => 'posts#new'
```

Pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def index
end

def home
end

def profile
if (User.find_by_username(params[:id]))
  @username = params[:id]
else
  redirect_to root_path, :notice=> "User not found!"
end

@posts = Post.all.where("user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id)
@newPost = Post.new

end

end
```

Posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id #assign post to the user who created it
    respond_to do |f|
        if (@post.save)
            f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Post created!" }
        else
            f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Post Not Saved" }
        end
    end
end

def show

end

def edit
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Your post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully deleted.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private

def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params #allows certain data to be passed via form
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :title, :description, :image)
end

end
```

Profile.html.erb

```
...
<%= link_to('Delete', post_path, :method => :delete) %>
...
```

Terminal

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               registrations#destroy
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                root GET    /                              pages#index
                home GET    /home(.:format)                pages#home
                     GET    /user/:id(.:format)            pages#profile
             connect GET    /connect(.:format)             pages#connect
                help GET    /help(.:format)                pages#help
            messages GET    /messages(.:format)            pages#messages
                 new GET    /new(.:format)                 posts#new
```

Comment: Do try and do database loads once and once only per controller action for things like a simple user record. You look it up, throw out the results, then look it up again later just to pull out the ID. This is extremely wasteful. If you have a proper relationship between User and Post you should be able to do `@user.posts.all` if you want.

Comment: I think your first step is to figure out exactly where the string 'testuser' is coming from. Also, what version of Rails are you using? In Rails 4+, `find_by_*` methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass id or instance in link of delete

```
<%= link_to('Delete', post_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

Should be pass a `post` instance on the delete link so that in find it find the post

```
<%= link_to('Delete', post_path(post), :method => :delete) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to('Delete', post_path(post.id), :method => :delete) %>
```